# Переделать скрипт для тача

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Нужна помощь. Как переделать этот скрипт, чтобы он аналогично работал на таче?

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {

      if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь так просто не обойтись. Вам надо либо посмотреть готовые плагины для работы с тачем в Asset Store, либо писать свою реализацию. Мышь это один указатель, который есть всегда активен и вы можете определить состояние кнопок нажата или нет. С тачем сложнее, не забывайте что тач касаний может быть несколько,
 а достучаться к ним можно через `Input.touches[]`.

Анализируете объект `Touch` для каждого касания и решайте что с ним делать. Если пишете свою реализацию, то придется еще и придумывать как обрабатывать жесты для 2, 3 и т.д. касаний, чтобы например поворачивать, масштабировать, слайдить и пр.